# RESTful service basic authentication

Tags: c#, rest

I just built a RESTful service on the base on this  tutorial  as an exercise.
So it is basically a Web API project created in Visual Studio 2013.

I've modified it so that it will return a JSON string containing some adresses. I've also written a small client application that basically just reads that string and put the adresses on the screen.

When I created the project I checked Identification using Individual User Accounts. So I have the ApplicationOAuthProvider available.

From here on though I am a bit lost. I find a lot of tutorials use some sort of self implemented basic authentication. But I wanted to stay as close to the template project as possible until I fully understand what I am doing.

My controler for requesting the data looks like this:

```
public IHttpActionResult Get()
{
    return Json(db.vwAdressen);
}
```

Using the [Authorize] filter I get (of course) an error message that I'm not authorized, though I don't know if that is all I need to implement authentication properly. And, of course, send a request with credentials.

Comment: If you're asking how to perform basic authentication i.e. authorize yourself from the client, have a look at this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication especially the **client side** part. If you send a header with that as it's content you should be properly authorized. If this is not your question I cannot help you any further.

Comment: @ldebruijn I spent yesterday reading everything I could find about basic authentication. And yes, sending a header with username/password did the trick. I got confused because all tutorials I found had selfwritten authentication methods on the server side and so I thought I was missing something

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For guarding my api with BasicAuthentication. I found using `Thinktecture.IdentityModel.Owin.Basic Authentication` library as the easiest to implement.

Get this nuget package from [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Thinktecture.IdentityModel.Owin.BasicAuthentication/)

Now in your `owin` `Startup` class write the following statement in your configure method -

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
   app.UseBasicAuthentication("MyAppAuthRealm", ValidateUser);
    ...
}
```

...where `ValidateUser` is the method which will actually validate your user using basic authentication.

And then implement the `ValidateUser` method something like this - (*To make things simple I have assumed the userName and Password to be equal for a valid user. Have you own logic for validating the user*)-

```
    private Task<IEnumerable<System.Security.Claims.Claim>> ValidateUser(string id, string secret)
    {
        if (id == secret)
        {
            var claims = new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, id),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Foo")
            };

            return Task.FromResult<IEnumerable<Claim>>(claims);
        }

        return Task.FromResult<IEnumerable<Claim>>(null);
    }
```

Now again in your `Configuration` method, use the following statement just before registering your web api config -

```
app.UseClaimsTransformation(TransformClaims);
```

Where `TransformClaims` is the method that transform claims to application identity.

```
    private Task<ClaimsPrincipal> TransformClaims(ClaimsPrincipal incoming)
    {
        if (!incoming.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return Task.FromResult<ClaimsPrincipal>(incoming);
        }

        // parse incoming claims - create new principal with app claims
        var claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "foo"),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "bar")
        };

        var nameId = incoming.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
        if (nameId != null)
        {
            claims.Add(nameId);
        }

        var thumbprint = incoming.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Thumbprint);
        if (thumbprint != null)
        {
            claims.Add(thumbprint);
        }

        var id = new ClaimsIdentity("Application");
        id.AddClaims(claims);

        return Task.FromResult<ClaimsPrincipal>(new ClaimsPrincipal(id));
    }
```

Now you can call your api from client like this -

```
        var handler = new WebRequestHandler();
        handler.ClientCertificates.Add(
            X509.CurrentUser
                .My
                .SubjectDistinguishedName
                .Find("CN=client")
                .First());

        var client = new HttpClient(handler)
        {
            BaseAddress = new Uri("https://myWebApp/api/")
        };

        client.SetBasicAuthentication("foo", "foo");

        var result = client.GetStringAsync("requestUri").Result;
```

> You can find sample from the owner for more details here - 
>   https://github.com/IdentityModel/Thinktecture.IdentityModel/tree/master/samples/OWIN/AuthenticationTansformation

Comment: here u gave answer for basic auth but when we use identity in asp.net mvc to authenticate user then what kind of auth is used there? tell me name and also tell me all different kind of auth name like basic which people use. thanks

Comment: @Mou Apart from Basic, there are many techniques for doing this, viz. Identity, individual accounts, public accounts like facebook, google etc, custom authorization service etc. This has some useful information - http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api

Comment: i just trying to know other names of auth like basic auth. Local login of Individual accounts is consider as basic auth? when there is basic auth then there must be funda like advance auth....just tell me what kidn of auth is consider as advance auth?

Comment: @mou: Then there is token based authentication.

Comment: i know token based auth. tell me Local login of Individual accounts is consider as basic auth or basic auth is something different ?